# Regex in powershell not matching regex101

Tags: regex, powershell

Trying to get data from crystal disk text file, in order to sort through the data i need to find out how many disks there are, when doing this in regex101 it gets the data fine but when i move this over to powershell it does not stop at the blank like like id expect but keeps going all the way past it, am i missing something i cant seem to find any reason as to why (i did try matches 0 aswell btw)

[here is the regex101 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XghXb.png)

```
function NumberOfDisks{

$fileContent = $rawReport

$pattern = '(?ms) Disk List (.*?)\n$'

[regex]::matches($rawReport, $pattern)
$result = $Matches[1]

Display-Alert -Message $result
```

}

and this is the result from powershell

```
Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 632
Length   : 12417
Value    :  Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------
            (01) ST1000LM048-2E7172 : 1000.2 GB [0/0/0, pd1]
            (02) SAMSUNG MZVLB256HAHQ-00000 : 256.0 GB [1/1/0, sq] - nv
           
           ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            (01) ST1000LM048-2E7172
           ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      Model : ST1000LM048-2E7172
                   Firmware : SDM1
              Serial Number : ZDEGC7GX
                  Disk Size : 1000.2 GB (8.4/137.4/1000.2/1000.2)
                Buffer Size : Unknown
                Queue Depth : 32
               # of Sectors : 1953525168
              Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
                  Interface : Serial ATA
              Major Version : ACS-3
              Minor Version : ACS-3 Revision 3b
              Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600
             Power On Hours : 1733 hours
             Power On Count : 815 count
                Temperature : 37 C (98 F)
              Health Status : Good
                   Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, NCQ, GPL
                  APM Level : 8080h [ON]
                  AAM Level : ----
               Drive Letter : D:
           
           -- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
           ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
           01 _69 _64 __6 000000705251 Read Error Rate
           03 _99 _99 __0 000000000000 Spin-Up Time
           04 _99 _99 _20 0000000005ED Start/Stop Count
           05 100 100 _36 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
           07 _78 _60 _45 0000043054AE Seek Error Rate
           09 _99 _99 __0 24E7000006C5 Power-On Hours
           0A 100 100 _97 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
           0C 100 100 _20 00000000032F Power Cycle Count
           B8 100 100 _99 000000000000 End-to-End Error
           BB 100 100 __0 000000000000 Reported Uncorrectable Errors
           BC 100 100 __0 000000000000 Command Timeout
           BD 100 100 __0 000000000000 High Fly Writes
           BE _63 _36 _40 000E2B130025 Airflow Temperature
           BF 100 100 __0 000000000003 G-Sense Error Rate
           C0 100 100 __0 00000000000C Power-off Retract Count
           C1 _84 _84 __0 0000000082F3 Load/Unload Cycle Count
           C2 _37 _64 __0 000C00000025 Temperature
           C5 100 100 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
           C6 100 100 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
           C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
           F0 100 253 __0 145900000335 Head Flying Hours
           F1 100 253 __0 00049D531417 Total Host Writes
           F2 100 253 __0 0005BBB519B7 Total Host Reads
           FE 100 100 __0 000000000000 Free Fall Protection
           
           -- IDENTIFY_DEVICE ---------------------------------------------------------
                   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
           000: 0C5A 3FFF C837 0010 0000 0000 003F 0000 0000 0000
           010: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 5A44 4547 4337 4758
           020: 0000 0000 0000 5344 4D31 2020 2020 5354 3130 3030
           030: 4C4D 3034 382D 3245 3731 3732 2020 2020 2020 2020
           040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 8010 4000 2F00
           050: 4000 0200 0200 0007 3FFF 0010 003F FC10 00FB 0110
           060: FFFF 0FFF 0000 0007 0003 0078 0078 0078 0078 0100
           070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001F 8F0E 0006 006C 0040
           080: 07F0 001F 746B 7D69 6163 7469 BC49 6163 017F 004E
           090: 004E 8080 FFFE 0000 D0D0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
           100: 6DB0 7470 0000 0000 0000 0000 6003 0000 5000 C500
           110: B67E 8218 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 401E
           120: 401C 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0029 6DB0
           130: 7470 6DB0 7470 2020 0002 0140 0100 5000 3C06 3C0A
           140: 0000 003C 0000 0008 0000 0000 BDFF 0280 0000 0000
           150: 0008 0000 0000 0027 1028 8000 4000 0100 A500 8000
           160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0003 0000
           170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
           180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
           190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
           200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 3035 0000 0000 4000
           210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1518 0000 0000
           220: 0000 0000 107F 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
           230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
           240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
           250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 32A5
           
           -- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
                +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
           000: 0A 00 01 0F 00 45 40 51 52 70 00 00 00 00 03 03
           010: 00 63 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 32 00 63 63 ED
           020: 05 00 00 00 00 00 05 33 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
           030: 00 00 07 0F 00 4E 3C AE 54 30 04 00 00 00 09 32
           040: 00 63 63 C5 06 00 00 E7 24 27 0A 13 00 64 64 00
           050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32 00 64 64 2F 03 00 00 00
           060: 00 00 B8 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BB 32
           070: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BC 32 00 64 64 00
           080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 BD 3A 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
           090: 00 00 BE 22 00 3F 24 25 00 13 2B 0E 00 00 BF 32
           0A0: 00 64 64 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 32 00 64 64 0C
           0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 01 C1 32 00 54 54 F3 82 00 00 00
           0C0: 00 00 C2 22 00 25 40 25 00 00 00 0C 00 00 C5 12
           0D0: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 10 00 64 64 00
           0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 3E 00 C8 C8 00 00 00 00 00
           0F0: 00 00 F0 00 00 64 FD 35 03 00 00 59 14 34 F1 00
           100: 00 64 FD 17 14 53 9D 04 00 00 F2 00 00 64 FD B7
           110: 19 B5 BB 05 00 00 FE 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
           120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 71
           170: 03 00 01 00 01 9C 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           180: 00 00 00 00 D8 11 00 00 00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
           190: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1A0: 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 91 6A 84 35 AD 05 00 00
           1B0: 00 00 00 00 01 00 60 00 17 14 53 9D 04 00 00 00
           1C0: B7 19 B5 BB 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 16 00 00 01 00 00 00
           1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
           1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 18 00 00 00 61
           
           -- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
                +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
           000: 01 00 01 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00
           010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 14 00 00 00 00
           020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           030: 00 00 07 2D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00
           040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 61 00 00 00 00
           050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           060: 00 00 B8 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BB 00
           070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BC 00 00 00 00 00
           080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 BD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           090: 00 00 BE 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BF 00
           0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00
           0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           0C0: 00 00 C2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 00
           0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 00 00 00 00 00
           0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           0F0: 00 00 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F1 00
           100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F2 00 00 00 00 00
           110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 92
           
           ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            (02) SAMSUNG MZVLB256HAHQ-00000
           ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      Model : SAMSUNG MZVLB256HAHQ-00000
                   Firmware : EXD7201Q
              Serial Number : S444NX0M820032
                  Disk Size : 256.0 GB
                  Interface : NVM Express
                   Standard : NVM Express 1.2
              Transfer Mode : PCIe 3.0 x4 | PCIe 3.0 x4
             Power On Hours : 681 hours
             Power On Count : 819 count
                 Host Reads : 9864 GB
                Host Writes : 5732 GB
                Temperature : 39 C (102 F)
              Health Status : Good (98 %)
                   Features : S.M.A.R.T.,
```

Comment: have tried /r/n aswell but same result

Comment: Is `$rawReport` a single multiline string (got using `Get-Content 'thefile' -Raw`) or an array of strings you obtained with `Get-Content 'thefile'` (so, without **-Raw**). If an array, there will be no newlines to match on.  If single multiline string, try with \r?\n

Answer (score 0):

As well as Theo's comment about making sure you have a string with newlines in it, vs an array of lines without them, your code here:

```
[regex]::matches($rawReport, $pattern)
$result = $Matches[1]
```

only the operator `-match` sets the `$Matches` automatic variable. The .NET method call `[regex]::matches()` does not. So this code says "send all the matches to the pipeline, and then look for $result in a null variable". This should really be throwing an exception "Cannot index into a null array" unless you used `-match` earlier in the script.

You need `$result = [regex]::matches($rawReport, $pattern)` and then see where you are.

Comment: Hi, yes using the -Raw aswell have also tried using matches aswell, swapped to match when it didnt work    $report = Get-Content $InfoFilePath -Raw

Comment: @G.Bushnell then I'll go with Theo's other suggestion, switching "\n$" for "\r\n\r\n".